# Razor Pages ASP.NET Core 3.1 - How To Dynamically create multiple radio button groups

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

I need to dynamically generate multiple radio button groups in a page and retrieve their values. Can anyone provide a simple example? I haven't been able to find one online.

Comment: Have a look at: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/radios

Comment: Is my answer helpful?If it is helpful,can you mark it as answer?Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo about using radio buttons and posting selected radio button value in razor page:

cshtml.cs:

```
[BindProperty]
        public string Selected { get; set; }
        public List<string> Radios { get; set; }
        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            //You can dynamically set Radios value here
            Radios = new List<string> { "0-10", "11-20", "21-30" };
            return Page();
        }
        public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            return OnGet();
        }
```

cshtml:

```
<form method="post">
        Age:<br />
        @foreach (var radio in Model.Radios)
        {
            <input type="radio" asp-for="Selected" value="@radio" />@radio<br />
        }
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
```

result:
[image]